# Combining object properties in a OO way

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a situation where I must send mail A and sometime I have to send mail B, but there are also situation where I want to send a mail which is consists of a combination of mail A and mail B.

For example mail A has as it's subject 'Subject of mail A'. Mail B's subject is 'This is the subject of mail B'. Now I have the situation where I want this as my subject: 'Subject of mail A / This is the subject of mail B'

How can I achive this using an OO way?

I already have two seperate classes for mailA and mailB.

Comment: Do mailA and mailB have a common interface or base class?

Comment: At this moment they have a common interface, but I can refactor this if necessarily

Comment: Create a + overload for instances of MailA and MailB, than add its properties value and send back the new combined object

Comment: Martijn, didn't my answer help you? Is something unclear? Please ask if this is the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a base class `Mail` - or an interface `IMail` - with the two properties `Subject` and `Body`, you can create a derived class `CompositeMail`:

```
public class CompositeMail : Mail
{
    private readonly List<Mail> _mails;

    public CompositeMail(params Mail[] mails) : this(mails.AsEnumerable())
    {
    }

    public CompositeMail(IEnumerable<Mail> mails)
    {
        if(mails == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("mails");

        _mails = mails.ToList();
    }

    public override string Subject
    {
        get { return string.Join("/", _mails.Select(x => x.Subject)); }
    }

    public override string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _mails.Select(x => x.Body));
        }
    }
}
```

This is an abbreviated implementation of the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). "Abbreviated", because it doesn't contain methods the add, remove or enumerate the children. If you want to add this functionality, simply make `CompositeMail` additionally implement `ICollection<Mail>`.

You can instatiate it like this:

```
var compositeMail = new CompositeMail(mailA, mailB);
```

You can use this instance anywhere where you use a normal mail, because it derives from the `Mail` class you use elsewhere.